# $x^n+y^n+z^n+u^n+v^n=(x+y+z+u+v)^{n-1}, 3 \le n \le 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$$\left\{\begin{eqnarray*}{}
x^5+y^5+z^5+u^5+v^5&=&(x+y+z+u+v)^4\\
x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+v^4&=&(x+y+z+u+v)^3\\
x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+v^3&=&(x+y+z+u+v)^2\\
xyzuv&=&1
\end{eqnarray*}\right.$$
Find the number of sets of solutions $(x, y, z, u, v)\in\mathbb R^5$ that satisfy the system of equations.

This is the multinomial formula
$$(x_1+x_2+⋯+x_m)^n=∑_{k_1+k_2+⋯+k_m=n}{n \choose k_1,k_2,…,k_m}∏^m_{i=1}x_i^{k_i},$$

where

$${n \choose k_1,k_2,…,k_m}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!⋯k_m!}$$

This only helps for the expansion of the RHS of the equations, but does not help with the question. I do not know how to continue from this point.

Comment: For nonnegstive $x,y,z,u,v$ there is only one possibility $(1,1,1,1,1)$ because we have $(x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+v^3)(x^5+y^5+z^5+u^5+v^5)=(x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+v^4)^2$, so we have (due to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) $x=y=z=u=v$. However, $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is not a solution as @IvanNeretin has mentioned below.

Comment: So does this mean the system of equations has no solution (answer is 0)?

Comment: well if $(x,y,z,u,v)=(1,1,1,1,1),$ then the first equation is false